# Is it possible to define a min padding on a li?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal unordered list as main navi.
The list elements have a min padding-right of 1rem for 640px width viewport and the padding-right should increase up to 3rem when the viewport is larger.
How can i achieve this?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-nav">Women</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-nav">Men</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-nav">Stores</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="lifestyle" href="/lifestyle">Lifestyle</a>
  </li>
  <li class="language">
    <a href="#">FR | EN</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

I made a demo:
https://codepen.io/StandardNerd/pen/JXOJMX

Comment: 1) what''s the minumum/maximum resolution to take into account 2) the padding should increase always or should stop at a given resolution?

Comment: 1) the minimum resolution should be 640px width and there is no maximum resolution limit.
2) the padding should increase up to 3rem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` position to achieve the same result

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqEQvQ)

Optionally you may set a `max-width` to the list to create more space around the first and last list-item if needed, e.g.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 76%;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```